# WebGL just stopped working locally for no reason

Tags: webgl

I was playing with some WebGL tutorials and, for no reason, WebGL just stopped working.  I even loaded an untouched WebGL HTML page that I downloaded from the web that worked fine before.  When I FTP that same exact code to my web server and load it, it works fine.  Two questions...

1. Why would WebGL all of a sudden just stop working locally across ALL browsers?
2. Why would WebGL HTML code run fine online, but not locally?

I should also mention I restarted my computer, uninstalled/reinstalled Chrome and Firefox, and cleared all my internet cache.

Thanks so much for all your wisdom!

Answer (score 5):

Found the problem.  To prevent a local page from accessing your whole hard 
disk drive, each local file:// URI is its own domain, which means that 
local textures are always treated as cross-domain. In Firefox, I was able to get around this by modifying the about:config and setting security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false

Comment: In Chrome you can pass `--allow-file-access-from-files`. In both cases you can serve the files locally with `cd path/to/page; python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and then you can point your browser to http://locahost:8000  Then you don't need any flags in your browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to work around this problem:

Use some IDE like Netbeans or Visual Studio to run your application. They use a local server automatically, so you don't have to run it on your own server or mess around with your browsers. Letting browsers access local data is more or less a security issue.